# is there an alternative SaveCopyAs property in VBA that can allow password protect?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a part of a my array script that moves the data into a template, works so quickly. Thing is, I have a `SaveCopyAs` property that doesn't support password protection.

Does anyone know of something similar that will allow for a password to be appended?

```
        Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
          ValidFileName(Mgr & "_" & Last & "_" & "Realty Services Assessment.xlsx")
```

Ideally, I'd want everything the same, but just a `password:= "_______"` part in there, as well.

Comment: Use `wb.SaveAs` instead? (will need to close the book and then reopen the original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SaveAs` instead. That will make the copy be the active workbook though, so you'll want to close that copy and re-open the original if you want to preserve the exact same behavior:

```
originalPath = wb.FullFileName
wb.SaveAs ...path...password...
wb.Close
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(originalPath)
```

Comment: Or use `SaveCopyAs` then open the copy, save as read-only, and then close it.